# Change height of a trigger field in EXTJS 4

Tags: extjs, triggers, height

the trigger field height is too small IMO..

[image]

as you can see... the button on the right is bigger. I have tried

```
height: 40
```

but the height of the trigger field does not change. Is there another way of changing the height.

Comment: [read this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Trigger-cfg-triggerCls) it may help full for you

Comment: thank you sai... I already did but could not find anything that could help me solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **partially** solve this problem by adding the following CSS rule:

```
.x-form-field-wrap .x-form-trigger {
    height:40px;
}
```

The button has a fixed image thus has a fixed height. Sencha needs to solve this problem.